# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_file_create()

Tags: php, curl, cron, telegram

If I run script with browser, it works good.

But an error comes out through the scheduler.

`$tg->photo2(-1001216648524 , '/banners/'.$a.'.jpg');`

```
public function     photo2($id, $message, $caption, $reply) {   
        $data = array(
            'chat_id'      => $id,
            'photo'     => curl_file_create(__DIR__ . $message),
             'caption'     => $caption,
            'reply_markup'     => $reply,
   
            );
       
        $out = $this->request('sendPhoto', $data);
    
        return $out;
    }
```

Comment: scheduler might be using php version < 5.5. can you verify it on your terminal: `php -v`

Comment: php version 5.4.16 (native)

Comment: yup it's not supported in php version less than 5.5